# Laptop video edit

Tags: video

Well, i have a laptop and i want to do some professional work on video editting. But I can use only my laptop which runs ubuntu 14.04. I am mainly using OpenShot. I need to create a lot of 3d titles - i have already created some but i need more. Is it safe for my laptop to have its processor running all the time with a temperature of 81°C at 80-100 % load? Some video edits require the cpu running at these stages for about 3 hours! Is it safe to continue my work or I should stop immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT!
You will be fine the processor does not crap out till about 100 Cel.  At your current temp readings your computer will be ok to handle the heat and the load required for what you are doing on it.

Comment: You are righr! Sorry!! :) wel, i have an intel core 2430m installed on a toshiba satellite l750-1gn

Comment: Yes but doing so everyday isn't harmful;

Comment: All in moderation.  no more than 8 hours a day.  Hope this doesn't hinder you.  Its the thread/cycle load more than a simple heat.

Answer (score 0):

81C is a max, worry if it goes over. Try not to block the air vent either, and if you can, stick a vacuum hose to it every once in a while to clean the dust out.

I wouldn't worry, if the laptop does overheat it'll shut itself down (instantly, losing your work - so save often).

Comment: The max °C provided by Intel is 100°C. It sometime goes up to 91°C after very hard vudeo editting! Should i worry? May i continue editting? I have a cooling base and i cleaned its inside the last summer (2013 summer).. So??